# Reading From File in Java and Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm pretty new to java and I've got a problem that I couldn't solve by myself. I googled the exception but problem is too specific as far as I can understand so I find myself here. Here is my problem.

I have a class called Student which has fallowing data members and their get/set methods:

```
private String studentNumber;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;
private String gender;
private String country;
```

and I created an array of instances as fallowing:

```
Student studentList[] = new Student(10);
```

I got a database(a text file) as fallowing

```
081935 Cengiz rrrrr Male 21 Turkey
082935 Ayşe aaaaa Female 22 England
083935 Onur bbbbb Male 23 Germany
084935 Fatma ccccc Female 24 Cyprus
085935 Ali dddd Male 21 China
086935 Zehra eeee Female 22 Denmark
087935 Murat ffff Male 25 France
088935 Selin ggggg Female 26 Japan
086935 Cengiz hhhh Male 20 Korea
080935 Damla qqqqqq Female 19 Iran
```

What I'm trying to do is getting all these informations to my class instances and I try to achieve this is fallowing:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentTracker  {

    private static int counter = 0;
    private static Student studentList[];

    public static void readFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("Database.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        try {
              while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                processLine(scanner.nextLine());
              }
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }


    public static void processLine(String line) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
        scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
          studentList[counter].setStudentNumber(scanner.next());
          studentList[counter].setFirstName(scanner.next());
          studentList[counter].setLastName(scanner.next());
          studentList[counter].setGender(scanner.next());
          studentList[counter].setAge(Integer.parseInt(scanner.next()));
          studentList[counter].setCountry(scanner.next());      
          counter++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Empty or invalid line. Unable to process.");
        }
      }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        studentList = new Student[10];
        readFromFile();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.printf(studentList[i].getStudentNumber(), " ",
                              studentList[i].getFirstName());

        }

    }

}
```

but it gives fallowing error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at StudentTracker.processLine(StudentTracker.java:28)
    at StudentTracker.readFromFile(StudentTracker.java:16)
    at StudentTracker.main(StudentTracker.java:68)
```

by the way couldn't find a function like C-scanf which gets the input until first white space so I find another way to parse the strings from line with

readFromFile() and processLine functions but I'm not sure if they're workig as intended.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
studentList = new Student[10];
```

creates an array of 10 elements. The value of each element isn't a `Student` *object*; it's a *reference* - and that reference will either be null, or a reference to a Student object (or a compatible type). Each element has a null value to start with.

**That line doesn't create any `Student` objects**.

You need to create an instance of `Student` before you set its properties, e.g.

```
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
  studentList[counter] = new Student();
  studentList[counter].setStudentNumber(scanner.next());
  ...
```

Or:

```
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
  Student student = new Student();
  student.setStudentNumber(scanner.next());
  ... fill in the other properties ...
  studentList[counter] = student;
  ...
```

As a side note, this line:

```
private static Student studentList[];
```

... is not an idiomatic declaration. It's valid, but most Java programmers would prefer to see:

```
private static Student[] studentList;
```

That way all the type information is kept in one place. (I'd also suggest using a `List<Student>` instead, and passing it into the method rather than using a static variable, but let's not get ahead of ourselves...)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from not initializing the elements in `studentList`, also here

```
    if (scanner.hasNext()) {
      studentList[counter].setStudentNumber(scanner.next());
      studentList[counter].setFirstName(scanner.next());
      studentList[counter].setLastName(scanner.next());
      studentList[counter].setGender(scanner.next());
      studentList[counter].setAge(Integer.parseInt(scanner.next()));
      studentList[counter].setCountry(scanner.next());      
      counter++;
    }
```

you check `scanner.hasNext()` only once, then call `scanner.next()` several times. This will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if any nonempty input line has less elements than expected.

OTOH checking `hasNext()` before each field assignment is very awkward. An alternative may be to use [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). This produces a `String[]`, and you can check its length to ensure that all fields are present, before trying to initialize the new student object.

Comment: it seems my parser is not working properly. It only parses student IDs. I don't know what's wrong with code

Comment: @cengizkandemir if your file would contain only one student ID, it would fail.

Comment: @cengizkandemir, try debugging your code, or putting `println` statements to the important places, to see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made it working. It's just a simple assignment so database is fully in my control.

Answer (score 1):

You created an array of Student but never put any Student objects in it.

Instead of setting them as array indexed values, create a new object, set its properties then assign it to the array index.

```
for( ... ) {
 Student x= new Student();
 x.set...
 studentList[index]= x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your processLine you are referencing studentList[counter] but you never put a new Student into studentList[counter] so you are trying to call setStudentName on null.  You should put a new student into the studentList at couter and then use it, or to make it more readable, do something like

```
Student = new Student();
student.setThis( scanner.next());
student.setThat( scanner.next());
studentList[counter] = student;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have pasted what is on line 28 where you are getting the exception. A couple things to check:

1. Is `studentList[counter]` non-null?
2. After checking that `scanner.hasNext()` is `true` you are calling `scanner.next()` several times. Can one of those calls return a `null`? This cannot be the root-cause here as the exception would have at least one more method on the stack, but you still probably need the check in your code.

Answer (score -1):

With

```
Student studentList[] = new Student(10);
```

you're just creating an array of Student type, of size 10. This array contains 10 references of Student, each reference is not yet defined (it'll be a null).

Before invoking any set method on Student reference, instantiate the object like this

```
studentList[counter] = new Student();
```

So your code may become like

```
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        studentList[counter] = new Student();
        studentList[counter].setStudentNumber(scanner.next());
```